# Drawable resource using a variable

Tags: android

I want to use a variable instead of R.drawable.myimage because I have a database with the image's names. I get the name from the database and I want to use the drawable resource with this name.

```
String flagimage = "R.drawable." + myHelper.getFlagImage(5);
int resourceId = Integer.parseInt(flagimage);
Bitmap flag = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**You can use the name of a resource like**

`getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage);`

```
getResources().getIdentifier("us","drawable","com.app");
```

The above function will return an integer value same as R.drawable.us.

This is how you access with resource names.

Comment: Just a quick note [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) returns `0` if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

Answer (score 18):

You can use this code to get the identifier...

```
 Resources res = this.getResources(); 
 int resID = res.getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Comment: After alot of search it worksss greattt work . Thanks

Comment: use of getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code